# How to forge a jar timestamp?

Tags: jar, timestamp

Without changing my whole system clock, and without using a VM.

There are no options un the 'jar' executable (on linux), and `touch`-ing everything in the past didn't change the manifest.

Is there a tool or some scripting language package someone could use to forge a jar from the past (or the future) ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by "a jar from the past". Which elements of the jar do you want to alter?

Comment: I would like to alter every timestamp in the jar, in order to get the same jar I could produce .e.g two days ago. (with the same files)